# Imported module fails to import sub-module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I have the following folder-structure

```
premier_league/
 |_cli_stats/
    |__ __init__.py
    |__cli_stats.py
    |__get_data/
         |__get_stats.py
         |__get_id.py
         |__api_scraper/
              |__api_scraper.py
```

In `cli_stats.py` I have the following import:

`from get_data.get_stats import SeasonStats`

In `get_stats.py` I have the following import:

`from api_scraper.api_scraper import Football`.

When running `python cli_stats.py` from the `cli_stats` folder the following error occurs.

```
  File "cli_stats.py", line 36, in <module>
    from get_data.get_stats import SeasonStats
  File "/Users/name/Desktop/Projekt/premier_league_api/cli_stats/get_data/get_stats.py", line 12, in <module>
    from api_scraper.api_scraper import Football
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_scraper'
```

But when running `python get_stats.py` from the `get_data` folder, the import is successful. Why does the import not work when running `cli_stats.py` from the `cli_stats` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the import to a relativ one. From the`get_stats.py`you have to step into the directory. The error is that `from api_scraper.api_scraper import Football` is an absolut import.

Try: in get_stats.py

```
from .api_scraper.api_scraper import Football
```

(1 dot before the api_scraper)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, that solved the problem. Could you perhaps point me to any resource where where when to use relative/absolut imports are explained? Thank you for the help!

Comment: I would recommend the official site: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Otherwise this might be helpfull: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to provide the resources, highly appreciated!